# Dialog with three radio buttons in angular2 nativescript

Tags: dialog, popup, radio-button, nativescript, angular2-forms

I am new to angular2 native script programming.. i want to  create a dialog with 3 radio buttons for my mobile app. i know there have some inbuilt dialogs like login,prompt,action...etc. i want 3 radio buttons on a dialog. how i can create such dialog? please help me out..
i tried the action dialog.. but there have no radio buttons.

//simple action dialog

```
dialogs.action("Select Your Option", "Cancel", ["option 1", "option 2","option 3"]).then(res=> {
                console.log("Dialog result: " + res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A radiobutton is not a standard mobile UI component but if that actionsheet you're using doesn't cut it you can use a plugin like https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox

[This is an example of that plugin in action](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-pluginshowcase/blob/79aa6b5e438081036b3dd4e09c99cfbfb323d314/app/input/input.component.html#L74-L79) and this is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm not going to copy-paste all the code over to SO, sorry.